# Self referencing relation with followers|friends users

Tags: orm, kohana, relationship, kohana-orm

To make relationship between users was created a table that looks like.

```
sql
CREATE TABLE `friends`(
 `from` INT NOT NULL,
 `to` INT NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE INDEX(`from`, `to`)
 );
```

As you may know - field `from` and `to` is a keys of `user_id` from `users` table.

I'm using Kohana 3.09 with its default module Auth.

Question is...

*How to make ORM functionality around relations of users with (default) Model_User class?*

Is there any needle to create additional class or perhaps i had some mistakes with relations one_to_many trouth and many_to_many trouth cause it did not work.
Please help.
My best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this section of the documentation:

http://kohanaframework.org/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany

You'll need something like this within your user class

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'friends' => array(
        'model' => 'user',
        'through' => 'friends',
        'far_key' => 'from',
        'foreign_key' => 'to',
    )
);
```

These options are used [at this part in the source code](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/7edd666dc248c9521aff9730d2883a0f89347418/classes/kohana/orm.php#L349).

Comment: i'll test it well today. cause i've already been test such like and it's haven't give me the result i wanted. ty, will see

Comment: If it doesn't work, see if you can find out what SQL query it used, that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Lethargy, I believe it should be `far_key` not `far-key`

Comment: How can I create FOREIGN_KEY that delete all relations when a user is deleted?

Comment: That's more of an SQL question than a Kohana question. I suggest googling or posting your own question.