# PHP SQL join relations

Tags: php, sql, join, kohana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self referencing relation with followers|friends users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685191/self-referencing-relation-with-followersfriends-users)

Hi there.

I have two tables called `users` and `users_friends`.

users:

```
id INT
username VARCHAR
.....
```

users_friends:

```
user_id INT
friend_id INT
PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`friend_id`)
```

How can I get the information about a specific users friends? Let's say I want to list friends associated with the user with an `id` of `5`.

Can't get my joins working, everything I try ends up with no result. Any ideas? This should be I simple query with two `INNER JOIN` I think but can't manage.

Then a second question is how do I structure this using Kohana 3.1 ORM? Perhaps I shouldn't?

EDIT: Anyone have an idea about doing this with Kohana 3 ORM?

Comment: what does friend_id refer to? the users table?

Comment: yes, 'friend_id' is another users id

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this :

```
select users.*
from users
    inner join users_friends on users_friends.friend_id = users.user_id
where users_friends.user_id = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `users_friends` AS uf ON u.id = uf.user_id
WHERE u.id = '5'
```

this is the query with `INNER JOIN`

if all of the information is stored in users you will need to join `users` once more

```
SELECT ufu.*
FROM `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `users_friends` AS uf ON u.id = uf.user_id
INNER JOIN `users` AS ufu ON uf.friend_id = ufu.user_ud
WHERE u.id = '5'
```

Comment: I want to fetch all the user (with id 5) friends infromation. This return information about the user (with id 5)

Comment: @sandelius the second query will return it :)

Comment: This helped me with my first q :) thx

Comment: How can I add a FOREIGN_KEY that deletes all relationships when a users is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse a JOIN is possible, but that wont be faster then a simple query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT friendID FROM user_friends WHERE userID=5
)
```

But, this only lists the friends from user 5. If you want the other way around, so list the people that say user 5 is a friend, this query is also easier to alter.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT userID FROM user_friends WHERE friendID=5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it a simple:

```
Select friend_id from users_friends where user_id = 5
```

`5` being the users id.

Comment: no, I want to get the information about the friends of the current user

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
SELECT friend_id, username
FROM users_friends JOIN users
  ON users_friends.friend_id = users.id
WHERE user_id = 5;
```